# Arabic text multiple results

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a table with Arabic text. There are two unique rows:

اِس 
اُس

The first one consists of the following characters :      0x0627, 0x0650, 0x0633
The second one consists of the following characters:  0x0627, 0x064F, 0x0633

The problem is if I query for either of these, they both show up. This happens both on the command line and using phpmyadmin. Here is what I type for a query:

SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT urdu FROM transliteration WHERE urdu LIKE 'اِس';

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your collation set to `utf8_bin`? Otherwise MySQL will probably see them as same characters because they are merely different casings of the same character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This return of both strings happens to be a feature (a useful feature!) of MySQL: SELECT statements can be insensitive to the case or vowel length of characters.  This feature is  called collation. utf_unicode_ci is probably the collation on your column called `urdu`.

But you can control this in your WHERE clause if you need to.

```
WHERE COLLATE utf_bin urdu = 'اِس'
```

(Please forgive me if I mangled your Arabic; I am ignorant of that language.)

But, please consider that MySQL may already be giving appropriate results for your application once you finish debugging it and put it into production.

Notice also that you don't need to use LIKE unless you're hoping for a partial match.

Comment: You are completely correct. I just noticed that I never responded to this, but that was the answer (over a year ago)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the same word, one has a short vowel, the other not. Since short vowels are optional you can use both versions. Now MySQL seems smart enough to drop the vowels and return you the same entry. Maybe you need to drop the LIKE argument from your query because both versions are alike.

If you want to avoid this kind of problem strip your db entries from all short vowels and save the original word in a second row. Then you can also strip all your queries and search for identical entries.

Comment: It's not a `LIKE` thing, it's a collation thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT urdu FROM transliteration WHERE urdu LIKE 'اِس' collate utf8_bin
```

Or rather add `collate utf8_bin` at the end in your code, I'm not sure I got the characters right.